# How do you generate an overlay like Jing has in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay

I am learning c# right now and I figured it would be cool to rebuild something like Jing (just the screenshot part no video).

I am wondering how I create an overlay like this: [http://files.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-07-26_2210.png http://files.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-07-26_2210.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/5910/Jing/2009-07-26_2210.png)

You click your mouse and the see through part it takes a picture of.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Brian Scott's: [Cropper - Point and shoot screen captures](http://cropper.codeplex.com/)

Includes C# source.